# Symfony validator with dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony4, symfony-3.4

I want to validate an object with constraint annotations, and use dependencies (entityManager) at the validator.

The validator does not work, if it has dependencies (eg. entityManager) in the constructor.

I followed the docs, but it does not work:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies

**"ClassNotFoundException
Attempted to load class "validator_question_exists" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?"**

I try to validate the 'Question' object like this (maybe here is the problem):

```
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
    ->enableAnnotationMapping()
    ->getValidator()
;

$question = new Question();
$errors = $validator->validate($question);
```

Question (the object to validate)

```
/** @App\Validator\Constraint\Question\QuestionExists() */
class QuestionReadInput{
    ....
}
```

services.yaml

```
services:
    validator.unique.question_exists:
        class: App\Validator\Constraint\Question\QuestionExistsValidator
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: validator_question_exists}
```

Constraint

```
namespace App\Validator\Constraint\Question;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class QuestionExists extends Constraint
{
    public $message;

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        //if i delete this function, symfony cant autowire the entitymanager to the validator
        //this throws an error, wants to make a new validator_question_exists(), which not exists, because its a service alias, the docs said it should be okay
        return 'validator_question_exists';
    }
}
```

Validator

```
class QuestionExistsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
          die('I dont see this message...');
    }
```

debug:container

```
Information for Service "validator.unique.question_exists"
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       validator.unique.question_exists
  Class            App\Validator\Constraint\Question\QuestionExistsValidator
  Tags             validator.constraint_validator (alias: validator_question_exists)
                   validator.constraint_validator
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes
```

Comment: I think your tags for the validator should just be: `tags: ['validator.constraint_validator']` and be done with it. also remove the `validatedBy`, because it will use the `validator.constraint_validator` you aliased, which doesn't make any sense at all. you could have used `validator.unique.question_exists` (the appropriate validator), but removing it will lead to the classname getting a `Validator` appended and looked for. if it's in the same namespace, it should work.

Comment: changed the tag format (but i think it doesnt matter), tried with validatedBy return 'validator.unique.question_exists', got same 'classNotFound exception' as above.
Yes, the validator is in the same namespace with 'Validator' appended to the classname.
If i remove the validatedBy class, still cant autowire the entitymanager:
"Too few arguments to function App\Validator\Constraint\Question\QuestionExistsValidator::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www.../web/vendor/symfony/validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 43 and exactly 1 expected"

Comment: Can you explain why you create the `Validator` instance yourself instead of using the `validator` service provided by Symfony?

Comment: as xabbuh said, the building of a validator by yourself probably produces the error, also the `validatedBy` method apparently has to return the *class name* of the validator, not a service descriptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the default symfony Validator, as @xabbuh mentioned, and it worked.

```
__construct(ValidatorInterface $validator){
    $question = new Question();
    $errors   = $validator->validate($question);
}
```

I should have not create my own validator with Validaton::createValidatorBuilder.

It does not matter if you use this config:

```
App\Validator\Constraint\Question\QuestionExistsValidator:
    tags: ['validator.constraint_validator']

with no validatedBy()
```

or that:

```
validator.unique.question_exists:
    class: App\Validator\Constraint\Question\QuestionExistsValidator
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: validator_question_exists}

with:

public function validatedBy() {
    return 'validator_question_exists';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring the service yourself, then you should also be adding it's arguments:

```
services:
    validator.unique.question_exists:
        class: App\Validator\Constraint\Question\QuestionExistsValidator
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator }
```

Other than that it should work without any tag aliases or `validatedBy` method.

Sidenote: for quite a while now in Symfony it's recommended to name (id) your services by the class names, that way auto-wiring could handle your service, and you wouldn't need the class parameter, i.e.:

```
services:
    App\Validator\Constraint\Question\QuestionExistsValidator:
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator }
```